# avocado plant recently replanted into larger pot is drying up - is being watered

Tags: avocado

I transplanted my 6 year old avocado plant from a 12x12 inch pot into a 12x36 inch clay pot. I spread out the root ball and set the plant down about 12'' from the surface. My plant has dried up drooping leaves. This happened about two weeks ago, and I've since watered it once a week with a quart of water. What can I do to help the plant?

Comment: a picture would help

Comment: You spread out the roots. I am sure the plant is going through some shock. Give it some time and alter the watering regime to 3/4 quart every 3 days.

Comment: As root bound as it's likely to be, I wouldn't be surprised if all your water weren't flowing around the edges of the root ball. If you didn't spread the roots, water by soaking in the sink for awhile. Eventually the avocado will figure out it's got some new soil to grow roots out into.

Comment: When you say you 'spread out' the rootball, what precisely does that mean? It suggests you broke it all apart and physically separated and spread out the roots yourself - did you?

Comment: yes - i did spread out the roots-thanks all - will monitor and post results-